# Could an exe file modify included text files?

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I am really really new to python.
So I am working on a Tkinter quiz game with an option that allows users to add their own questions and answers. Basically, the program reads the dictionary file stored in a text file and makes amendments to it. It works well in the source code but not in the .exe file I generated using Auto Py to Exe, where I added the text file to the main python program and transformed them into a single .exe file.

Below is the part of my code

```
def add_pair():
    Entry1 = Entry(root, width=12, font=('Arial', 15))
    Entry1.place(x=150, y=240)
    Entry2 = Entry(root, width=12, font=('Arial', 15))
    Entry2.place(x=300, y=240)

    def Add():
#   read_file is the data extracted from the text file
        global read_file
        read_file[Entry1.get()] = Entry2.get()
        w = resource_path('storage.txt')
        write_save = open(w, 'w+')
        write_save.write(str(read_file))
        write_save.close()

    button = Button(
        root,
        text='Add New!',
        font=('Arial', 12),
        width=10,
        command=Add,
    )
    button.place(x=470, y=240)
```

It seems that the .exe file could not make changes to the text file that is added to it. Is there any method to make changes to included text files in an executable file?

Comment: No this isn't a hard and fast rule of exe files, its more likely another bug. Perhaps the .exe can't find the file? Or the .exe doesn't have appropriate permissions?

Comment: “The .exe file could not make changes to the text file”: please be specific, what error are you getting? Also, do you mean the changes appear to be made but when you runt the program again they are lost?

Comment: In short, could an exe program edit a text file added to itself as a data file (not in the same directory as the exe)? As my current exe only reads it but cannot make changes to it.